# How can same points have different current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, short-circuit, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

[image]

Aren't B and D the same point and shouldn't it actually be (B and B)?

If they aren't the same point what should be the current from B to D?

Why is it 2 amperes (from the answers) and not 10 amperes as it should be (because the two 1ohm and 4 ohm connected in parallel are in series with the 2 ohm and 3 ohm in parallel?

Another question is why should there be any current through the 3ohm resistance at all? Isn't the wire a short circuit and shouldn't current flow through the short circuit across the the 2ohm as it offers less resistance?
What is actually going on?

---

[image]

If I can calculate the total current using the 2nd circuit as equivalent to the 1st, doesn't that mean that 10 A is flowing through BD? Can I take the red wire as BD or can I not? If not, why?
Where is BD in the 2nd (equivalent) circuit?
Isn't BD the same point in the equivalent circuit? Or do I have to come back to the 1st circuit after calculating the current from the 2nd (equivalent) circuit? If yes, why do I have to come back to the 1st circuit?
Can I not have my BD wire in the 2nd circuit? If not, how is it the equivalent circuit of the 1st one in the first place?

Comment: There is more than one way to solve this. That is one reason that we like to see your work, so that we won't use a solution method that you haven't learned. Here is how I would solve it. Assume that C is the reference point (0 volts). Then, A = 20 V. Find the voltage at B (ignore D for now, calculate the parallel value of the resistors). Then find the current in each resistor. Then use KCL to find the unknown current at node B.

Comment: Think about this: if wire from C to battery has equal voltage but current flowing through it, why can't wire from B to D have same voltage and current through it? And what would be the point of calculating resistance of parallel resistors if current only takes the least least path of resistance? What kind of lecture notes you have from your course?

Comment: Hi, Shadman. You have many responses and comments. But I see nothing written in response to any of them coming from you. You write very well in your question. But to help you, we need to *hear* how your mind processes what you can read here, already. It may be that no one has 'hit it just right' for you. If so, say so. You don't have to know exactly what's wrong. But we need to listen to what's still missing for you from what's already written here. (If anything is missing.) I'd be tempted to try an entirely unique approach, but without input from you I'm not sure it would help. So write?

Comment: @jonk extremely sorry sir. I'm from Bangladesh and my mother tongue isn't English so I was taking a while to fully understand before commenting something that others might find hard to understand.

Comment: @ShadmanSakib Understood. You use English quite well -- colloquially. I only wish I spoke a 2nd language so well as you do! (My 2nd language is German.) Take your time, then. Thanks for acknowledging your presence and interest!

Comment: @ShadmanSakib Have a look at [these alternative views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5XJ.png). Do you see why pinching things off in one way is different than pinching them off in the other way? (Looking from left to right?)

Comment: @jonk Yes they do seem different. So how should I relate it to my circuit?

Comment: @ShadmanSakib The question is asking you to work out the current from **B** to **D** (or visa versa.) On the left, I created a little box of connection between the four resistors. The upper two corners are both part of **B**. The lower two corners are both part of **D**. If you pinch the two vertical sides of the 'box' together, left side to right side, so that there is a single wire going from **B** to **D** you haven't changed the node names. But if you pinch the two horizontal sides of the 'box' together, top to bottom, then you have *merged* a **B** with a **D** on the left. Same on right.

Comment: @ShadmanSakib So in this latter case you have changed the question. It's no longer about the current from **B** to **D** but now about the current from left-side **BD** to right-side **BD'**. And that's not the same question as before. So you won't necessarily get the same answer from that approach. You could, if you wished, insert 0 V voltage sources on the left-most side schematic I show, replacing each wire in the box, and work out the currents in all four of them. That might be interesting for you to see, too, and think about.

Comment: @ShadmanSakib [Does this picture help you?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWU9F.png)

Comment: @jonk so you are saying that in the 2nd image that I added, the circuit 1 is the one for which the question is being asked (the original question) and the equivalent 2nd circuit that I draw isn't that same? Not equivalent? The question isn't same for my 2nd circuit?

Comment: @ShadmanSakib Different questions. Look at my last picture. Look at the sum of the horizontal currents. Look at the sum of the vertical currents. Note: they are NOT the same. Your 2nd circuit is looking at the horizontal currents. But this isn't the question that was being asked. It was asking for the vertical currents. See? Think of that middle node as a spread out sheet of metal -- a square.

Comment: @jonk okay so we were taught in school to reduce the circuits into easy manageable circuits to solve them. So I see the question and I try to reduce it. I then reduce it to the 2nd circuit. I can only calculate the horizontal current in this second circuit flowing from the left side BD to the right side BD right? The current is 10A if (r1 P r4) 
 series (r2 P r3).. right? So I can use this horizontal current to find out the vertical current in the first circuit? So I changed the circuit (and the question) then from that circuit found the horizontal current of circuit 2 and using that....

Comment: And using that I found the vertical current of circuit 1?

Comment: @jonk what about the case when instead of pinching the square I squeeze it into a small point? Am I not allowed to do that? How is B and D different then? doesn't that make B and D the same point?

Comment: @ShadmanSakib If you squeeze them down to a point then you have a **BD** point.  Coming into that point you will have 8 amps in the 1 Ohm resistor and 2 amps in the 4 Ohm resistor and leaving that point you will have 6 amps in the 2 Ohm resistor and 4 amps in the 3 Ohm resistor. But you will no longer be able to answer the question. The question wants to know the current that remains ***after*** the 8 amps arriving from the 1 Ohm resistor has had 6 amps removed away by the 2 Ohm resistor, before it can happen that the rest of it (2 amps) heads towards the lower resistors.

Comment: @jonk Thank you so much Sir. You have cleared all my confusion and doubts. I don't know how to thank you more..

Comment: @ShadmanSakib I am so glad it helped!! Thanks very much for letting me know. This site doesn't encourage 2-way exchanges like this. But often, that's exactly what's needed so that two people can listen to each others' minds working and share internal concepts. Each person facing a question brings their own internal states of mind to it. Others need to 'hear' this song, listen closely, and then try to find a way to adjust those internal states of mind (the melody line) so as to improve the view. Can't be done well with Q&A format such as here. Dialog is the way. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aren't B and D the same point and shouldn't it actually be (B and B)?

From a voltage point of view, you are right.

I deal with the node naming issue the following way. Voltage nodes are labeled with a lowercase letter. Current nodes always have an associated voltage. A voltage node may have one or more current nodes. So I name current nodes as a numerical subscript to a voltage node. This allows all current nodes within the same voltage node to have the same letter designation indicating the voltage while having a unique label. So your nodes B and D become b1 and b2 respectively.

For branches I use the label for current as the label from the branch since the definition of a branch is a cascade of elements in series and so all have the same current called the branch current.
The other answers have calculated the currents, so I won't do it again. What I want to discuss is the equivalences and differences between the two configurations, shown below. So I hope the labeling I have chosen will help clarify.

The two configurations are not the same but they are  equivalent for the for the following reasons.

1. The load seen by the voltage source is the same.
2. The voltages and currents across and through all the resistors are the same.
3. The node voltages measured to an arbitrary reference are all the same.

Making these measurements cannot identify the configuration.
Example: The labeling used allows \$V_{bc}\$ to mean the same in both configurations.

What is different between the two configurations is the current nodes within voltage node \$b\$. For clarity the current nodes in the first configuration are labeled \$b_{1}\$ and \$b_{2}\$, while in the second configuration they are labeled \$b_{3}\$ and \$b_{4}\$. They are not the same nodes as KCL will identify.

Measuring the current flows in and out of the node within node \$b\$ will identify the configuration.

So what happened to \$b_{1}\$ and \$b_{2}\$ in the second configuration?

Nothing happened. They just don't exist there. I don't agree that there is some sort of drifting electrons across the diameter of the conductor. Testing with magnetometer should be able to answer this question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW02o2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXwAGj.png)</sup>

> Another question is why should there be any current through the 3ohm resistance at all ? Isn't the wire a short circuit and shouldn't current flow through the short circuit across the the 2ohm as it offers less resistance? What is actually going on?

Two things you can always count on:

1. Current leaving one end of a component must enter the other end of the component.
2. Charge always flows in a closed path regardless whether it is easy or tortuous.

Really these two are different takes on conservation of charge.

It is always a good endeavor to identify the path(s) the charge flow takes to return to its source. It will change direction, divide or split at various nodes.

I hope my notation will help in understanding currents within a network of components.

Answer (score 6):

> Aren't B and D the same point and shouldn't it actually be (B and B)?

If you were analysing voltages then yes, B and D are the same node on the circuit. In this case, however, we're looking at current flow so different labels are applied to make it clear which points in the circuit we are referring to.

> If they aren't the same point what should be the current from B to D?

That's what you are being asked to calculate.

> Why is it 2 amperes (from the answers) and not 10 amperes as it should be (because the two 1ohm and 4 ohm connected in parallel are in series with the 2 ohm and 3 ohm in parallel?

- 4 Ω || 1 Ω = 0.8 Ω.
- 2 Ω || 3 Ω = 1.2 Ω.
- 0.8 Ω + 1.2 &Omega = 2 Ω (the resistance seen by the 20 V source).
- The current **from the 20 V source** = 20 / 2 = 10 A.

The 10 A current is split between the parallel resistors and since the ratios of the upper pair and lower pair are not equal some current will flow through the BD bridge.

> Another question is why should there be any current through the 3ohm resistance at all ? Isn't the wire a short circuit and shouldn't current flow through the short circuit across the the 2 ohm as it offers less resistance? What is actually going on?

You seem to be falling into the "current takes the path of least resistance" error. It doesn't. Current in each branch is inversely proportional to its resistance. That is, **current will flow in every branch but more will flow in the lower resistance branches**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTrqHj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The simulation result for the circuit with ammeters in each branch.*

Note that the BD branch has 8 + 2 = 10 A coming in from the left and 6 + 4 = 10 A exiting on the right. The BD link passes the current difference from one side to the other.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBbLQy.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. If the BD link is replaced by a bar you will still have a 2 A current drifting across the bar.*

Comment: Please read my edited comment and then please read this-

Comment: If I can calculate the total current using the 2nd circuit as equivalent to the 1st, doesn't that mean that 10 A is flowing through BD? Can I take the red wire as BD or can I not? If not why? Where is BD in the 2nd(equivalent) circuit? Isn't BD the same point in the equivalent circuit? Or do I have to come back to the 1st circuit after calculating the current from the 2nd (equivalent) circuit? If yes ,why do I have to come back to the 1st circuit? Can I not have my BD wire in the 2nd circuit? If not, how is it the equivalent circuit of the 1st one in the first place?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: If the BD link is replaced by a single wire as you showed in figure 2, wouldn't only 10A will pass through it? If 2A passes through it how does it become 10 and how does R3 and R4 get 6A and 4A then? Shouldn't the current in the red wire in figure 2 be 10A?

Comment: Yes the current through the red wire from left to right will be 10 A. The current from top to bottom will be 2A. You'll have 8 A entering the top-left corner, 2 A entering the bottom left. You'll have 6 A leaving the top right corner and 4 A leaving the bottom right. So, you must have 2 A flowing from top to bottom of the bar.

Answer (score 3):

First calculate R1 || R2, the total resistance formed by the parallel resistors R1 and R2.

$$R1 || R2 = \frac{R1 \times R2}{R1+R2} = \frac{1 \times 4}{1 + 4} = \frac{4}{5}\Omega$$

Then R3 || R4

$$R3 || R4 = \frac{R3 \times R4}{R3+R4} = \frac{2 \times 3}{2+ 3} = \frac{6}{5}\Omega$$

The total resistance is then

$$\frac{4}{5}\Omega + \frac{6}{5}\Omega = 2\Omega$$

The total current is

$$\frac{20V}{2\Omega} = 10A$$

The voltage across R1 or R2 is

$$V_{R1} = \frac{\frac{4}{5}}{2}\times 20V = 8V$$

So, the current through R1 is 8A, the current through R2 is 2A.

The voltage across R3 or R4 is 12V.

So the current through R3 is 6A and the current through R4 is 4A.

Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) says the algebraic sum of all the currents flowing into a point is 0. The currents flowing into point B are the current through R1, the negative of the current flowing through R3, and the negative of the current flowing from B to D. So the current flowing from B to D is 8A - 6A = 2A.

Applying KCL to point D, gives the current from B to D as -(2A - 4A) = 2A. As one would expect, the answer is the same whether you choose to apply KCL to point B or to point D.

Answer (score 2):

First, search the potential on center point B -> Vbc =12 V, and Vab=8V.

Current in 1 Ohm is 8 A. Current in 4 Ohm = 2 A.
Current in 2 Ohm is 6 A. Current in 3 Ohm = 4 A.

Do the balance and you find the current through B-> D = 2A.

It is not the same result if 1 and 4 Ohm are tied together in series with 2 and 3 Ohm tied together.

Comment: Why is it not the same result if 1 and 4 Ohm are tied together in series with 2 and 3 Ohm tied together? If I find the equivalent resistance assuming that the 1 and 4 Ohm are tied together(parallel) in series with 2 and 3 Ohm tied together(parallel) and divide by the voltage I get 2A current.

Comment: Another way to solve the first OP picture is by considering B-D wire as a resistor Rx. Calculate "literally" the current through this resistor and search the **limit when Rx goes to zero** ...

Answer (score 2):

You've combined the resistances correctly to find the 10A flowing through the combination.  Now, use the *current divider* equation to split the currents flowing through each parallel combination of resistances.  Note that the phrase "path of least resistance" is misleading since the figurative interpretation implies that only one path is "traveled" while the literal, electrical interpretation is somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion stems from the fact that you correctly recognized B and D to have the same potential, meaning that for the sake of analyzing the *rest* of the circuit you can consider them the same node.  However, that does not mean that there is no current flowing between them.  In fact, to get to the zero potential difference, it is likely that some current needs to flow.

There are lots of ways to figure out that current.  You can determine the total resistance (as you have done), calculate the total current from there, and then noticing, like you did, that the total current is 20V/((AB|AD)+(BC|DC)), split that total current into the currents AB and AD, and also split the same total current into the currents BC and DC.  Now you'll notice that the currents AB and BC are not identical, and it is the difference that needs to be accounted for by a current running from B to D.

Another possibility is to *remove* the connection BD and then calculate the resulting voltage on nodes B and D, and the respective total resistance between nodes B and D (for calculating that resistance, replace every voltage source with a short and every current source with an open connection).

Then the current after connecting B and D will be this voltage difference divided by the resistance between those points, a rather interesting property of electric networks that is by no means trivial to prove but very handy to use.

Answer (score -4):

First of all you dont have any resistors in parallel or in series.Lets solve your circuit using Y-Δ transform.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEdS1v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Lets focus on this part of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmND1g.png)</sup>

This is a Δ configuration circuit and it is equivalent to a Y configuration circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNXvEL.png)</sup>

\$R_{a} = \frac{4\cdot1}{4+1+0} = \frac{4}{5}\Omega \$

\$R_{b} = \frac{0\cdot1}{4+1+0} = 0\Omega \$

\$R_{c} = \frac{0\cdot4}{4+1+0} = 0\Omega \$

so the circuit can be redrawn like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy38nF.png)</sup>

But 0Ω means short circuit and when you replace Rb and Rc with a short circuit you find the equivalent circuit.

Questions:

> Another question is why should there be any current through the 3ohm resistance at all ? Isn't the wire a short circuit and shouldn't current flow through the short circuit across the the 2ohm as it offers less resistance?

If you see the equivalent circuit I have drawn obviously the current inside the 3Ω resistor is not 0.

> Why is it 2 amperes (from the answers) and not 10 amperes as it should be (because the two 1ohm and 4 ohm connected in parallel are in series with the 2 ohm and 3 ohm in parallel?

You dont have any resistors in parallel or in series.

> Aren't B and D the same point and shouldn't it actually be (B and B)?

They are the same point.Take Ohm's law \$ I = \frac{V}{R} \$

If both \$ V \$ and \$ R \$ are 0 then we get a indefinite result \$ \frac{0}{0} \$ so any current could be flowing inside a short circuit.

Comment: "But you cannot know the current flowing inside a short circuit." Of course you can. Perhaps not always, but there is no general rule against it. Downvoting. Also, R1 and R2 are parallel, as are R3 and R4.

Comment: "*You don't have any resistors in parallel or in series.*" There are clearly two pairs of parallel resistors in the OP's diagram.

Comment: This is plain wrong. There are two pairs or parallel resistors, and these pairs are in series with each other.